# jQuery add class to active tab

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery that is displaying content when a div is clicked...

  Link 1
  Link 2
  Link 3
  Link 4
  Link 5

```
<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>
```

```js
$(".link").click(function() {
    $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wqc9N/6/

It is working great, what i want to do now though is add a class to whichever tab is active so that I can style it.  Does anyone have an example I can look at to try and apply to my code?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does this have 3 negative votes?

Comment: I guess we will never know...

Comment: For those of you wondering (especially any newbies that may see this). I suppose the downvotes are simply due to framing the question as "Does anyone have an example I can look at to try and apply to my code?".   If the questioner had asked,  "I tried `xyz` and it didn't work, can anyone help?" It probably wouldn't be downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$( function() {
    $(".link").click(function() {
      if( $( this ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
         return;
      }

      $(".link").removeClass( 'active' );
      $( this ).addClass( 'active' );

      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
});

$( function() {
    $(".link").click(function() {
      if( $( this ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
         return;
      }

      $(".link").removeClass( 'active' );
      $( this ).addClass( 'active' );

      $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

Edit per follow-up question in the comments:

If you want to have the parent container be active, just use jQuery's parent().

For Example:

```
$( function() {
    $( '.link' ).on( 'click', function() {
        var $parent = $( this ).parent();

        if( $parent.hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
            return;
        }

        // Could use parents() here instead of closest if you are not in a nest li...
        $( '.link' ).closest( 'li' ).removeClass( 'active' );
        $parent.addClass( 'active' );

        $( '.content-container div' ).fadeOut( 'slow' );
        $( '#' + $( this ).data( 'rel' ) ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
    });
});
```

Comment: That works great, thanks for that.  I have changed the question slightly to include my links within li tags.  How would I change the code to apply the active to the li in stead of the a?

Comment: Updated solution with alternative for what you're asking

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) and [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/):

```js
  $(".link").click(function() {
    $(".link").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
```

```css
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 1</a>

<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 2</a>

<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 3</a>

<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 4</a>

<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 5</a>

<div class="content-container">
  <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
  <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
  <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
  <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
  <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

```js
var $links = $(".link").click(function() {
  $('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');

  //if all link elements are siblings
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
  //else
  //$links.not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.content-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
.content-container div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.link.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 1</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 2</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 3</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 4</a>
<a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 5</a>

<div class="content-container">
  <div id="content1">This is the test content for part 1</div>
  <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
  <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
  <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
  <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>
```